Как определить статус Linux-процесса в Go: .wait() vs .exited()?
Использую exec.Command для запуска процесса. Какой метод лучше для определения статуса: .wait() или .exited(), учитывая их ограничения?
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "10")
err := cmd.Start()

